# how to find a parent id if child id is given in shell script

Tags: linux, shell

I have a shell script in which I am trying to find all the parents of the process which is calling the shell script. I am able to fetch the immediate parent but I am not able to fetch the complete hierarchy.

`ID=$PPID
 echo $ID`

Now I want to fetch the parentID of the $ID. Can you explain how to do it?

Comment: See here: http://superuser.com/questions/150117/how-to-get-parent-pid-of-a-given-process-in-gnu-linux-from-command-line

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/150117/how-to-get-parent-pid-of-a-given-process-in-gnu-linux-from-command-line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply:

```
ps -o ppid= "$ID"
```

But to properly save it to a variable:

```
read NEXT_PPID < <(exec ps -o ppid= "$ID")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need a full tree use `pstree` somthing like:

```
pstree -s $ID
```

Or

```
ps -o ppid=$ID
```